# How can I get values using key in Carbon Fields from Multiselect?

Tags: post-meta

I have Multiselect field, created using latest Carbon Fields (2.2.0) library:

```
Field::make( "multiselect", "available_on", "Available on" )
    ->add_options( array(
        'windows' => 'Windows',
        'mac' => 'Mac OS/ OSX',
        'linux' => 'Linux',
        'android' => 'Android',
        'mobile' => 'Mobile',
        'tv' => 'Smart TV',
        'desktop' => 'Desktop',
        'router' => 'Router',
        'raspberrypi' => 'Raspberry Pi',
    ) ),
```

But when I use `carbon_get_post_meta()` and render it using `foreach()` or `var_dump()`, I get only key of the selected values (for example 'mac'). 
The value don't exist into DB, only keys.

So, how can I get these values (for example 'Mac OS/ OSX')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Carbon Fields developers here.

Thank you for your feedback!

Currently, the Carbon Fields stores only the keys and they don't have a built-in method to retrieve the selected values from the options array.

You can pass a callable which returns an array with the options as an argument to the `add_options` method.

```
function available_options() {
    return array(
        'windows' => 'Windows',
        'mac' => 'Mac OS/ OSX',
        'linux' => 'Linux',
        'android' => 'Android',
        'mobile' => 'Mobile',
        'tv' => 'Smart TV',
        'desktop' => 'Desktop',
        'router' => 'Router',
        'raspberrypi' => 'Raspberry Pi',
    );
}


Field::make( 'multiselect', 'available_on', 'Available on' )
    ->add_options( 'available_options' ),
```

Then use the function when you want to retrieve the correct values from the stored keys:

```
$all_options = available_options();
$available_on = carbon_get_post_meta( $post_id, 'available_on' );

foreach ( $available_on as $option_key ) {
    echo $all_options[ $option_key ];
}
```